# python pyparsing unstructered text file

Tags: python, pyparsing

Below I have a text file which I wanted to convert it to csv file.

```
+---------------------+--------------+---------------+
| column_date         | column_id    | column_desc   |
+---------------------+--------------+---------------+
| 2001-01-01 00:00:00 | 12345        | abc bar       |
| 2001-01-01 00:00:00 | 4567         | defg          |
+---------------------+--------------+---------------+
```

the expected output I am looking is:

```
column_date,column_id,column_desc
2001-01-01 00:00:00,12345,abc bar
2001-01-01 00:00:00,4567,defg
```

is there any example to do this by pyparsing?
Thanks.

Comment: If you are sure that un-necessary characters is +--------+----- , just remove it from the file

Comment: Is it necessary to use the pyparsing module?

Comment: @yabberth, no I thought pyparsing would be more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

## Possible Solution

```
import re

with open("file.csv", "r+") as myFile:
    content = myFile.read()
    regex = r'^\|\s+(.+)\s+\|\s+(\w+)\s+\|\s+(.+)\s+\|$'
    print(content)
    match = re.findall(regex, content, re.MULTILINE)
    [print(line[0]+","+line[1]+","+line[2]) for line in match]
```

### Output

```
|---------------------+-----------+-------------|
| column_date         | column_id | column_desc |
|---------------------+-----------+-------------|
| 2001-01-01 00:00:00 |     12345 | abc bar     |
| 2001-01-01 00:00:00 |      4567 | defg        |
|---------------------+-----------+-------------|

column_date        ,column_id,column_desc
2001-01-01 00:00:00,12345,abc bar    
2001-01-01 00:00:00,4567,defg
```

You may want to remove unwanted whitespaces before printing